# how to select specific index in 3rd matrix from third dimention in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I know this is a simple question but difficult to formulate in one sentence to google the answer.So, I have a 3d matrix with size 2x2x3 like this

```
A(:,:,1) =[1     1;  1    1];
A(:,:,2) =[2     2; 2     2];
A(:,:,3) =[4     4; 4     4];
```

and matrix B with size 2x2

```
B = [ 1 2; 2 3];
```

What i need is to chose from each third dimension in A just one number using matrix B:

```
for i=1:2,
  for j=1:2,
    C(i,j) = A(i,j,B(i,j));
  end
end
```

How to that in one line without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a single line, but without a loop:

```
[I J] = ind2sub (size(B), 1:numel(B));
linInd = sub2ind (size (A), I, J, B(:)');
C = reshape (A(linInd), size(B));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variation:

```
[r,c,~] = size(A);
[J,I] = meshgrid(1:size(B,1), 1:size(B,2));
idx = reshape(I(:) + r*(J(:)-1) + r*c*(B(:)-1), size(B));
C = A(idx)
```